# Как Яндекс.Контест тестирует код?

Tags: python, kotlin

Есть код на Котлин:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var count: Int
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    val sb2 = StringBuilder()
    sb.append(readLine()!!)
    count = sb.toString().toInt()
    sb.setLength(0)
    while (count > 0){
        sb.append(readLine()!!)
        if(sb.toString() != sb2.toString() ){
            println(sb.toString())
        }
        sb2.setLength(0)
        sb2.append(sb.toString())
        count--
        sb.setLength(0)
    }
}
```

в сервисе "Яндекс.Контест" он получает вердикт "memory-limit-exceeded" или "Превышен лимит использования памяти": https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jJmYJNlxY-_du4FDs8T-90E1FxPAlR9i

Прошу дать совет, как переработать код чтобы этот вердикт не выскакивал?

Comment: весь смысл в правильном выборе алгоритма и структур данных, а не языка, тем более на питоне тоже тесты валятся

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, дело в том, что после чисел в строках есть пробелы. В котлине первая считывается строка, например как `"5 "`, и при `toInt()` вылетает исключение (вердикт RE). Чтобы этого избежать используйте функцию `trim()` для строки прежде чем конвертить в `Int`. Плюс у вас не оптимальный алгоритм. У вас Memory Limit в питоне из-за вашего массива. Зачем он вообще нужен? Сразу выводите значение (там, где вы добавляете), вместо добавления в массив.

Comment: К сожалению Ваш совет не помог, видимо причина в другом.